# Open Microsoft Word using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I use the code below to set a form field named "Text1" for Microsoft word in PhP, but I got an error at the line `$word->Documents->Open('C:/Doc1.doc');`, which is  `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference` as shown below, what is the problem?

```
<?php
com_load_typelib('Word.Application');
$word = new COM("word.application");
$word->Documents->Open('C:/Doc1.doc');
$word->Visible = 1;
$word->ActiveDocument->FormFields("Text1")->Result = "something";
$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
unset($word);
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$word->Documents->Open is declared to require a parameter passed by reference and cannot be called with a string literal.

You need :

```
$docName='C:/Doc1.doc';
$word->Documents->Open($docName);
```